# Sprockets require_directory problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sprockets, asset-pipeline

I'm using Yahoo's *reset.css* in my new generated Rails 3.1 app. Given following app structure:

```
 - myapp
   - app
     - assets
       - stylesheets
         - application.css
   - ...
   - vendor
     - assets
       - stylesheets
         - yahoo
           - reset.css
           - fonts.css
```

Including the reset.css files inside my `application.css` using the `require_directory` directive following ends in `require_tree argument must be a directory`.

```
 /*
  *= require_directory ./yahoo
  */
```

Do I got something wrong or is this a Sprockets related bug? Because moving the reset.css files into `app/assets` works like a charm.

(Btw got the problem too in my Rails 3.0 app using a custom Sprockets env.)

Comment: `http://stackoverflow.com/a/7605094/390014` is also helpful

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, [@josh answered my question](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/issues/183#issuecomment-2007808):

Seems I need some kind of a proxy file (`yahoo.css`) which will be included in my `application.css`:

```
/*
 *= require_directory ./yahoo
 */
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of your proxy file and how you included in application.css. I am having the same problem and I do not really understand the solution. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The code above is the content of the proxy file! ;)