# Rails 3.1: javascripts not served correctly from vendor/assets directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I have organized my javascript files in a couple of directories and I have found the following strange behavior. Given the following tree:

```
+ app
  + assets
    + javascripts
      + common
      + public
        + common
        + home
          - home.js
```

`home.js` looks like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require_directory ../../jquery_plugins
//= require_directory ../../common
//= require_directory ../common
//= require_self
```

Now the trick lies in the `jquery_plugins` directory. I placed this inside `vendor/assets/javascripts` (which is included in the asset load path, when I check `Rails.application.config.assets.paths`). When I do this I get the error: `require_tree argument must be a directory`. When I move that directory to `app/assets/javascripts` then everything works.

Does anybody have a clue as to what I'm doing wrong? Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 27):

You could add a manifest file to the directory you are trying to serve with something like 
`vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery_plugins/manifest.js`

```
//= require_directory .
```

and require it in your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` via

```
//= require jquery_plugins/manifest
```

### Edit (even simpler way)

Thanks to @LeEnno for this

You can actually put all your single library related files in a folder named after the library for example `vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap` and in that same folder add an `index.js` which will act as your manifest and Rails will automatically pick it up

if in your

```
app/assets/javascripts/application.js
```

you add the line

```
//= require bootstrap
```

SO EASY!!!
Link to [Rails Asset Pipeline Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#using-index-files)

Comment: I am still doing this so if there is a reason for the negative votes, I would love some feedback.

Comment: way cleaner than the up-voted one...what is wrong with people

Comment: This does seem cleaner, I like it. I'm hesitant to do this, though, because I like to have *only* vendor code in vendor/, so that if I'm changing or updating stuff in there I don't have to worry about overwriting code I've written. I suspect similar thinking is where the (former?) downvotes came from.

Comment: @jpadvo - this does keep everything in the `vendor/assets` folder. Maybe I don't understand your issue.
- this was downvoted three times I think, haven't deleted comment because then @Plattsy's comment wouldn't make any sense :D

Comment: @pferdefleisch Lol. Anyway, the manifest file would custom code for your project (even though it is really simple). I don't like creating any files in vendor/ even simple ones. This is a pretty clean approach, though, and all told might be worth it.

Comment: If you rename the *manifest.js* to *index.js* you can simply do `//= require jquery_plugins` in *app/assets/javascripts/application.js*. This is what the [Rails Asset Pipeline Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#using-index-files) suggests.

Comment: @LeEnno Finally updating this :)

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem. I'm still not sure if it's a bug or intentional behavior, but it seems that `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` only works for single files, i.e. `require jquery` and so on. Apparently the asset load paths are just used to return the best match for a single `require` but not for `require_directory`or `require_tree`.

In my case, to load all files from `vendor/assets/javascripts`, I had to add the following to my `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`:

```
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/.
```

In your case something like this should work:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require_directory ../../../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery_plugins
//= require_directory ../../common
//= require_directory ../common
//= require_self
```

It seems that you always have to use the relative path from file where you're calling `require_directory` or `require_tree`.

Also, I found this discussion on the structuring of JS-assets to be helpful: [Rails 3.1 asset pipeline and manually ordered Javascript requires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149961/rails-3-1-asset-pipeline-and-manually-ordered-javascript-requires)

Comment: Yep, same goes with `*= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/.` for stylesheets.